# Pycharm does not show output in console, but displays "import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))"

Tags: python, import, pycharm, sys

When I am running a Python program file, Pycharm does not show the program output. Instead each time the following message appears in the screen:

```
C:\Data\Courses\Udemy\Triangular_Arbitrage\LexPythonScripts\Poloniex\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --host=127.0.0.1 --port=64870 
    import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
    sys.path.extend(['C:\\Data\\Courses\\Udemy\\Triangular_Arbitrage\\LexPythonScripts\\Poloniex'])
    PyDev console: starting.
    Python 3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:58:39) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

I checked stackoverflow for similar problems, but didn't find any adequate solution. Can anyone provide assistance with this? Thanks

I was expecting program output and, in fact, the same py file was giving output a few days ago. But after rebooting the PC I now only get the message that I described in the previous field.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that isn't the tab you are looking for. What you are looking in is the `Python Console` tab, which can let you code in a `REPL` fashion (you put some Python code in, and you get what that expression would output), like this:

[image: PyCharm's Python Console tab]
[image: The bottom tab bar]

You can go to the `Terminal` tab, and do `python <file you want to run>.py`
(which I do but don't recommand) to run the file manually, or:

[image: The Run tab, on top of a Hello World script]

When you press on the Run button (the green play button), or anywhere inside a program, PyCharm will create a `Run` tab, in which you will see your program's output, which looks like this:

[image: PyCharm's Run tab]

On the bottom tab bar, when you run the program, the `Run` tab will also show up there, and you can click on it to navigate to it. You will probably need to indicate to PyCharm that this file should be run, or make a Run Configuration yourself, but that's out of the scope of this question.

Good luck!

***TL;DR***: Look for a tab that says `Run` at the bottom bar of the screen.
[image: The run tab highlighted]